# Why is assignation not working in lambda function

Tags: javascript

Having

```
const assign = (a, fn) => {a = fn(a)}
```

and for instance

```
let a = 5
const double = (a) => a*2
assign(a, double)
a
```

still evaluates to 5. Same goes for Strings (which are objects).

Comment: It is working inside the function but the variable `a` inside `assign()` shadows the outer variable `a` which remains unchanged since they are not the same `a`

Comment: I got it, I didn't pay attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function parameters are passed by value.

You can instead make `a` an object, and modify its property.

```js
const assign = (a, fn) => {
  a.value = fn(a)
}
let a = {value: 5}
const double = (a) => a.value * 2
assign(a, double)
console.log(a.value)
```

Comment: indeed. I thought of something like reference and so. Strings are also passed by value then ? (just curious now that I have the solution)

Comment: @Curcuma_ all parameters are passed by value. Objects are passed by value too, but the value is the reference.

Comment: same as Java then. ok got ya

Comment: It's worth noting that passing by value means making a copy on the stack of the thing being passed. The reason the side-effect works in JS is that the values being passed (for non-scalar types) are references.